# Linear (mixed-effects) model for skewed and negative data / residuals

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, residuals, lme4-nlme

I am currently fitting a linear mixed-effects model to my data where the outcome variable can have both positive and negative values (integers).

The issue now is, that my outcome data is skewed with a  heavier tail in the positive direction. As a consequence, my residuals (as plotted with a qqnorm plot) deviate from a qq line in both directions.

Usually, I would go ahead and do something like a log-transformation, but in this case this is not possible as I have both positive and negative data. Using a generalized linear mixed-effects model does not solve my problem as well due to similar reasons (negative data).

A further thing to note is that I have a lot of data (multiple millions of samples).

Comment: 1. If your data is ordinal, "negative" makes no sense.  You can just add a constant because the numbers are meaningless.  2. Data cannot be skewed in both directions. 3. Log transformation of ordinal data makes no sense.

Comment: 1.) You are right, it is not ordinal per-se; it is a simple integer variable with positive and negative values. 2.) Skewed positively

Answer (score 4):

- The most likely effect of heavy-tailed residuals will be to give you unbiased point estimates with overly optimistic (too-narrow) confidence intervals and (too-small) p-values.  Depending on your goals, it might not matter that much if you have millions of data points ...
- If you actually have ordinal data, you should consider fitting an ordinal model! e.g `ordinal::clmm()` in R.
- The `robustlmm` package in R fits *robust* LMMs (see the vignette, i.e. `vignette("rlmer",package="robustlmm")` once you have downloaded/installed/loaded the packages).

Comment: I have updated my question regarding that I am not actually have ordinal data. Regarding your first point: I am mostly interested in the coefficients and p-values.